# Why do i need to use minitest/autorun?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rubygems, minitest

Why do i require `minitest/autorun` instead of `test/unit` for generating unit test

```
require 'test/unit'

class Brokened
  def uh_oh
    "I needs fixing"
  end
end

class BrokenedTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_uh_of
    actual = Brokened.new
    assert_equal("I'm all better now", actual.uh_oh)
  end
end
```

> Running the above code, interpreter raise warning
>
> > You should require 'minitest/autorun' instead

Comment: Because `test/unit` is deprecated : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28598052/2483313

Comment: @spickermann i wanted to know the reason behing it, i know code would work if i replace it, but y do i have to do that. Any insight

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code example will end in a NameError: `uninitialized constant Minitest`.

You have two possibilities:

- Use `test/unit` in combination with `Test::Unit::TestCase` or
- use `require 'minitest/autorun'` in combination with `Minitest::Test`.

`test/unit` is deprecated and it is recommended to use minitest (MiniTest is faster and smaller).

If you switch the test gem you must change perhaps some more things:

- replace `require "test/unit"` with `require "minitest/autorun"`
- replace `Test::Unit::TestCase with` with `Minitest::Test`
- There is no `assert_nothing_raised` ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499259/why-doesnt-minitestspec-have-a-wont-raise-assertion))
- `assert_raise` becomes `assert_raises`.
- perhaps some other issues

You may use `require 'minitest'` instead `require 'minitest/autorun'` - you will get no syntax error, but there is also no test execution. If you want to execute tests, you must call them on your own (see [minitest-a-test-suite-with-method-level-granularity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609208/minitest-a-test-suite-with-method-level-granularity))